# Cant install ziproxy

Tags: 12.04, installation, apt, package-management

I am trying to install ziproxy (http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/ziproxy) (http://ziproxy.sourceforge.net/download.html) using

`apt-get install zizproxy` but im getting this error below.

```
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree           
Reading state information... Done 
Package ziproxy is not available, but is reffered to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has ben obsoleted, or is only available from another source.
```

Why is this happening and how can i get around this or install it? It says i should be able to install using `` `apt-get install zizproxy `` i tried `sudo apt-get install zizproxy` and it still didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the Universe repo is enabled, and try the same command again:

[image]

```
sudo apt-get install ziproxy
```

Or download from [Source](http://ziproxy.sourceforge.net/download.html).

To enable Universe Repo from command line, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Once the file opens, make sure the lines below are in there, otherwise; add them in

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
```

Then do

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install ziproxy.

Comment: I am not using ubuntu desktop im using Ubuntu TLS Server. How would i do this on terminal?

Comment: See addition in the answer.

Comment: Im trying to install gedit on my ubuntu tls and its getting the same error, everything i try to install just gets an error saying

`ackage gedit is not available, but is reffered to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has ben obsoleted, or is only available from another source. 
E: Package gedit has no installation candidate
  `

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrdae`.  What  do you get?

Comment: Tried it already doesnt change anything I reinstalled the system several times too...

Comment: You are using Ubuntu Server 12.04LTS, right?

Comment: Yep thats the version

Comment: ubuntu-12.04.2-server-i386.iso is what i used to install it.

Comment: what is the output of `sudo apt-cache search gedit`?

Comment: no output just goes to the next line

Comment: I need to leave, but I will research this, and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks a bunch i will try to reinstall the server one more time but it probably wont change anything...

Comment: Zeeems to work now it was stupid VMWare doing easy install that didnt give me these packages and what not.